# Question about overloaded member functions in C++?

Tags: c++, overloading

I am reading some C++ text from the address https://cs.senecac.on.ca/~chris.szalwinski/archives/btp200.081/content/overl.html.
in the first lines, they say:

The signature of a member function consists of:

- the function name,
- the data types of its parameters,
- the order of the parameters and
  possibly
- **the const status of the function.**

I don't understand what they mean by saying "**the const status of the function**".

Can anyone elaborate on that, please?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++, you can declare a member function of a class to be `const`, by appending that keyword to its signature (for instance, `int MyClass:doSomething(int param) const {...}`). Doing so guarantees that the function won't change the (non-`mutable`) members of the class object on which the function is called - and hence it can be called with `const` instances of that class.

It is permissible to have two different member functions for a class whose signature differs only in whether they are declared `const` or not.

Comment: "won't change the (**non**-mutable)"? did you mean "mutable"?

Comment: @davka - No. You can declare a class member as `mutable` (as in `mutable int m_foo;`), which means it can be altered by `const` functions

Comment: I know. Now I see that you mean non-"mutable" as opposed to "non-mutable". It's quite hard to get the exact meaning if it's based on  text's background color :)

Comment: Okay. It was a toss-up between "he doesn't understand `mutable`" and "he hasn't spotted that I didn't write 'mutable'". Looks like I went the wrong way! Glad we're sorted now. :)

Comment: It might be worth also noting that the `volatile` qualifier participates in member-function overloading. Also, it's not a guarantee, but a promise, and promises can be broken.

Answer (score 3):

They mean to sum up the items of where functions must differ in order to be put into the same class scope. The `const` at the end is:

```
struct A {
  void f();
  void f() const;
};
```

These are valid overloads. The first is called if you call `f` on a `A`, and the second is used if you call it on a `const A`:

```
A a;
a.f(); // takes first

A const& b = a;
b.f(); // takes second
```

Note that the term "signature" is misused here. The signature of a function is more broad, and includes also the class of which a function is a member of. A signature uniquely identifies a function.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring a member function as `const` tells the compiler that the member function will not modify the object's data and will not invoke other member functions that are not const.

The compiler will check to make sure that you really don't modify the data. You can call a const member function for either a const or a non-const object, but you can't call a non-const member function for a `const` object (because it could modify the object).

You can read more about constness in C++ [here](http://www.possibility.com/Cpp/const.html).